# Is it possible to achieve true asynchronous programming in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I have been reading few articles around Multithreading and Asynchronous programming. From what I understand, true Asynchronous tasks doesn't need a new Thread to be created. But most of the articles I have gone through for Java implement Asynchronous programming using a new Thread (Either use a Runnable or Callable interface).

So my question - Is it possible to write code in Java that truly performs tasks Asynchronous

[This](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) blog post clearly states that Asynchronous task doesn't need a new thread.

[Blog1](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asynchronous-programming), [Blog2](https://rjlfinn.medium.com/asynchronous-programming-in-java-d6410d53df4d), [Blog3](https://medium.com/javarevisited/java-completablefuture-c47ca8c885af) claims to do tasks asynchronously but still use multithreading.

Comment: The first article you linked has very little to do with multithreading on the level of the JVM - you're talking about interrupts and register handling, which is handled usually on a C or ASM level. Java abstracts this notion away entirely, the code you write isn't concerned about it. Multithreading in Java then (whether virtual or platform threads) involves scheduling multiple units of work simultaneously.

Comment: Async just means some stuff is not done in a sequence. When you calculate the sum of two arrays respectively, you can sum up a then b, or e.g. first half of a, then b, then second half of a. This is obviously possible with one thread in Java. Async is a concept. When someone talks about threads and async, they talk about parallelism.

Comment: The "async" in the first blog post is a c# keyword. It is part of a _model_ of [_concurrent computing_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) that is supported by that language. "Threads" is a somewhat different, and arguably lower-level, model of concurrent computing that is directly supported by many operating systems. Because of the wide spread OS support for threads, you may sometimes find threads used to implement `async`-like features in some programming languages.